# Relationship between ListOjbect and TableObject

Tags: excel, vba

The Excel object model contains both a ListOjbect and a TableObject.  I am more familiar with a ListOjbect.

To provide context for this question, we may crudely divide a workbook into a GUI side, where people peruse and manipulate ranges and data without VBA, and the VBA side, where all data are objects or primitive types.

Although the VBA side has a class with the name ListObject, an instantiation of that class is referred to as a Table for users on the GUI side.

The  ListObject class defines a [TableObject property,](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listobject.tableobject).  A "TableObject object is a worksheet table built from data returned from a PowerPivot model."  Apart from the fact that it contains data from a PowerPivot model, "a worksheet table" sounds a lot like a ListObject.

I haven't found a lot of introductory information on what a TableObject is, and why one might be a property of a ListObject.  This is especially confusing, since the definition of a TableObject sounds a lot like a ListObject.

Can anyone please point to introductory information that describes the TableObject class, and its relationship to ListObject, in a more complete way than in the Microsoft documentation?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I found on https://exceloffthegrid.com/vba-excel-tables-code/ :

Tables, as we know them today, first appeared in Excel 2007.  This was a replacement for the Lists functionality found in Excel 2003.  From a VBA perspective, the document object model (DOM) did not change with the upgraded functionality.  So, while we use the term ‘tables’ in Excel, they are still referred to as ListObjects within VBA.

Comment: I do get that "Tables" are the name on the GUI side while ListObject is the class on the VBA side.  By why does a ListObject contain a TableObject property?